# How to run JS on a WebApp using AppleScript

Tags: javascript, safari, applescript, raycast

I saved Youtube Music as WebApp from Safari. I want to create an automation using AppleScript. It should run Javascript code on that WebApp.

I was trying to use something similar to what `youtube-music` extension does on `Raycast`.

```
tell application "${browser.name}"
    repeat with w in (every window)
        repeat with t in (every tab whose URL contains "music.youtube.com") of w
            tell t
                return ${runJS(browser.name, code)}
            end tell
        end repeat
    end repeat
end tell
```

[Link to code](https://github.com/raycast/extensions/blob/c524392d80b35348811bae59831f29bfdbc34432/extensions/youtube-music/src/utils.ts#L24)